# Is there a .NET data-type smaller than a byte?

Tags: .net, vb.net, types, byte, nibble

How about a Nibble etc.

Comment: BitOperations: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpLogicalBitwiseOps.aspx

Comment: youre welcome. :) Its not a .NET data-type but it will allow you to manipulate the bits within a byte. You mentioned bools, you might also consider this helpful: Bit Fields - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. Even if you have an array of Booleans, I believe they're specified to take up one byte each.

Of course you can define your own data types which have fewer than 256 valid values (like `Boolean` does) but you can't make it take up less than a byte in memory.

As LBushkin pointed out, there are types such as `BitArray` and `BitVector32` which effectively pack multiple bits efficiently - you could write your own `NybbleArray` type if you wanted.

Comment: I just took a look into the reflected BitArray, it's just a Boolean array with some functionality, for performance and portability it's not the best idea.

Comment: @Shimmy: Hmm... it's possible that I'm wrong about the space taken up by a boolean array, of course...

Comment: @Shimmy: I don't think that's correct. Looking at the reflected code myself, I see it is implemented as an `int[]` array, with each `int` value serving as its own packed group of bits.

Comment: @Dan, right, so anyway, it's definitely larger than a single Byte implementation (at least 4 bytes), so conclusion is, if you want to implement a Nibble, then it should probably be implemented with underlying Byte or SByte for best performance capabilities (don't forget it's a value type), or if you need it to play with single Nibbles, then I would better suggest to use the existing BitArray or BitConverter shared (static) methods or implement another shared class with your own functionality, or just embed it all in your byte-implemented Nibble structure, which is what I am going to do..

Comment: @Shimmy: I only meant to point out that it's designed in a way that makes sense -- i.e., what you would expect from a name like `BitArray` -- as opposed to "a Boolean array" as you described it, which would make it a pretty pointless data structure. As for what makes the most sense for performance capabilities, I'd say that depends entirely on your needs. Yes, if you want exactly 8 bits in the form of an immutable struct then sure, a `byte` makes sense. If you want 32 bits, I'd say an `int` makes more sense than 4 `byte`s. `BitArray` is mutable and intended to be used as such.

Comment: @Shimmy: In any case, if your intention is specifically to create a data type that is *smaller* than a `byte`, the purpose of these answers is to point out that this isn't possible; you can only store data smaller than 1 `byte` if you break up existing structures (`byte`, `int`, or otherwise) in such a way that they represent multiple pieces of information.

Comment: Right, but I want portable immutable objects that are less than a byte and not grouped, I guess I will simply use implementation of a Byte wrapper and that's it, cuz that's the smallest amount possible (in memory). thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to generate a compiler error if I try to set for the nibble any value higher than 0xF?

Comment: @Shimmy: No, I don't believe so.

Comment: @JonSkeet, gonna extend this conversation even more :) Anyway, I'm now working on a project that handles with binaries, and I thought about implementing a Nibble data-type. I copied the reflected code from System.Byte and made all the adaptions. Now, my question is, is there a way to instruct it like byte, i.e. `Nibble n = 0x7F;`?

Comment: @Shimmy: This should be asked as a separate question.

Comment: @JonSkeet Actually I think I already found the answer. The compiler resolves this automatically.

Answer (score 5):

There's no native data-type smaller than byte, however if you want to store and manipulate a group of packed bits, you can use [BitVector32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.aspx) or [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx).

Comment: I think I am gonna use simple Byte, since BitVector is 4 bytes (Int32) length (at least).

Answer (score 1):

No, byte is the smallest.

This may be helpful: [How can you nibble (nybble) bytes in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124960/how-can-you-nibble-nybble-bytes-in-c)

Comment: Less memory?  No.  Fewer possible values?  Yes.  If you are trying to implement a Nibble type then the best way would be to either use a BitArray/BitVector as previously mentioned or to use bitmasking on bytes.