# Convert a string of hexadecimal characters to an array of nibbles (interview experience)

Tags: c#, nibble

I have seen this question unanswered in an interview experience

first of all, I need to understand the question,

(a nibble corresponds to single hex character right?) so, if given Hex string  "12A" then the output should be

```
arr[0]=0001
arr[1]=0010
arr[2]=1010
```

is that correct or have i misunderstood?

if so how do i go about implementing this in C#? whats the type of **arr** here?

Comment: I think your last question there is a question for the one that interviews you. It could be string, it could be a numeric type. The format suggests numeric, but it also suggest base 10 notation, which is wrong/odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nibble is a four bit binary.  As such you need three nibbles to represent `12A`.

The `arr` you have there is incorrect - as there is no `2` in binary.

```
arr[0]=0001
arr[1]=0010
arr[2]=1010
```

For c# implementation see - [How can you nibble (nybble) bytes in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124960/how-can-you-nibble-nybble-bytes-in-c)