# Trying to reproduce PHP's pack("H*") function in C#

Tags: c#, php, md5, pack

this is my code in C# :

```
    public static String MD5Encrypt(String str, Boolean raw_output=false)
    {
        // Use input string to calculate MD5 hash
        String output;
        MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
        byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str); 
        byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

        // Convert the byte array to hexadecimal string
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        output = sb.ToString();

        if (raw_output)
        {
            output = pack(output);
        }

        return output;
    }

    public static String pack(String S)
    {
        string MultiByte = ""; 

        for (int i = 0; i <= S.Length - 1; i += 2)
        {
            MultiByte += Convert.ToChar(HexToDec(S.Substring(i, 2)));
        }

        return MultiByte;
    }

    private static int HexToDec(String hex)
    {
        //Int32.Parse(hexString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        return Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
    }
```

To reproduce what is done in php by this way :

```
md5($str, true);
```

OR

```
pack('H*', md5( $str ));
```

I tried many things but can't get the same on the two sides in some cases of word.
For example, Trying this test on the string "8tv7er5j"

**PHP Side :**

```
9c36ad446f83ca38619e12d9e1b3c39e <= md5("8tv7er5j");
œ6­DoƒÊ8ažÙá³Ãž <= md5("8tv7er5j", true) or pack("H*", md5("8tv7er5j"))
```

**C# Side** :

```
9c36ad446f83ca38619e12d9e1b3c39e <= MD5Encrypt("8tv7er5j")
6­DoÊ8aÙá³Ã <= MD5Encrypt("8tv7er5j", true) or pack( MD5Encrypt("8tv7er5j") )
```

Why ? Encoding problem ?

**EDIT 1 :**
I have the good result, but bad encoded with this this function for pack() :

```
if ((hex.Length % 2) == 1) hex += '0';

byte[] bytes = new byte[hex.Length / 2];

for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i += 2)
{
    bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
}

return bytes;
```

So, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes) give me :
�6�Do��8a���Þ

And System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
?6?Do??8a??????

...

Comment: Output them as bytes not as text and compare

Comment: I believe you are getting a difference because the php pack pattern `"H*"` refers to high nibble hex conversion. You aren't performing a high nibble conversion in C#. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124960/how-can-you-nibble-nybble-bytes-in-c) for more info on nibbles, specifically in C#.

Comment: I introduced recently C# dev, and relatively new with it. I got the good string with this : if ((hex.Length % 2) == 1) hex += '0';

            byte[] bytes = new byte[hex.Length / 2];

            for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i += 2)
            {
                bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
            }

            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString( bytes );  BUT the encoding seems bad, i tried ASCII and UTF8

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same scenario where I am in need of php's pack-unpack-md5 functions in C#. Most important was that I need to match out of all these 3 functions with php.

I created my own functions and then validated(verified) my output with functions at onlinephpfunctions.com. The output was same when I parsed with DefaultEncoding. FYI, I checked my application's encoding(*Encoding.Default.ToString()*) and it was **System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding**

**Pack**

```
    private static string pack(string input)
{
    //only for H32 & H*
    return Encoding.Default.GetString(FromHex(input));
}
public static byte[] FromHex(string hex)
{
    hex = hex.Replace("-", "");
    byte[] raw = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
    {
        raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
    }
    return raw;
}
```

**MD5**

```
    private static string md5(string input)
{
    byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input);
    byte[] hashedBytes = MD5CryptoServiceProvider.Create().ComputeHash(asciiBytes);
    string hashedString = BitConverter.ToString(hashedBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
    return hashedString;
}
```

**Unpack**

private static string unpack(string p1, string input)
    {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

```
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        string a = Convert.ToInt32(input[i]).ToString("X");
        output.Append(a);
    }

    return output.ToString();
}
```

*PS: User can enhance these functions with other formats*

Comment: This worked perfectly with me with slight changes. But my required output might be different from original questioner. So I have added a answer with my requirements. So it might be help to some one who want to convert php pack to c# code. But all code is use from Risky. So all credit should go to him. Check my answer below with name of "Dzero"

Answer (score 0):

I guess that PHP defaults to Latin1 so the code should look like :

```
public static String PhpMd5Raw(string str)
{
    var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
    var inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str); 
    var hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

    var latin1Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    return latin1Encoding.GetString(hashBytes);
}
```

Comment: The php page print that is encoded in UTF8. I tried your latin1 suggest, and thats give me this => 6­DoÊ8aÙá³Ã

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to feed the result as a key for HMAC-SHA1 hashing keep it as bytes[] and initialize the HMACSHA1 with the return value of this function: DO NOT convert it to a string and back to bytes, I have spent hours because of this mistake.

```
public static byte[] PackH(string hex)
{
    if ((hex.Length % 2) == 1) hex += '0';
    byte[] bytes = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i += 2)
    {
        bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. I am posting my answer for anyone who might reach this page searching for it.
The following code is the full conversion of the **pearl function pack("H*") to c#**.

```
public static String Pack(String input)
{
    input = input.Replace("-", " ");
    byte[] hashBytes = new byte[input.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
    {
        hashBytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(input.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
    }

    return Encoding.UTF7.GetString(hashBytes); // for perl/php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. I didn't go with the questions completely. But if php code is as below,

```
$testpack = pack("H*" , "you value");
```

and if can't read the $testpack values(due to some non support format), then first do base64_encode as below and echo it.

```
echo base64_encode($testpack);
```

Then use **Risky Pathak** answer. For complete this answer I'll post his answer with some small modification like base 64 encoding etc.

```
            var hex = "you value";
            hex = hex.Replace("-", "");
            byte[] raw = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
            {
                raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
            }
            var res = Convert.ToBase64String(raw);
            Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Now if you compare both of values, those should be similar.

And all credit should go to the **Risky Pathak** answer.

Answer (score 0):

The same in c# can be reached with Hex.Decode() method.
And bin2hex() in php is Hex.Encode().