# How to transform to C# the PHP pack('H40',$string);?

Tags: c#, php

I am trying to reproduce the result of a PHP pack('H40',$string) function.
So far i got good results but slightly different.
Here is what i tried

PHP Code

```
<?php
function test(){
   $packed = pack('H40',"42d5abcd859afd2cc0f6b6f8cc2a9cd41f66a120");
   return $packed;
}
echo test();
?>
```

C# Code:

```
private void test(){
    string result = PackH40("42d5abcd859afd2cc0f6b6f8cc2a9cd41f66a120");
}
private string PackH40(string input)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    input = input.Replace("-", " ");
    byte[] hashBytes = new byte[input.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
    {
        hashBytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(input.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
    }
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hashBytes);
}
```

The results look similar in browser but if you write them to a file they are not equal.
So far i tried every Encoding for the C# output and nothing.
What am i doing wrong?

Edit: 
I tried the approach in 
[Trying to reproduce PHP's pack("H*") function in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508193/trying-to-reproduce-phps-packh-function-in-c-sharp) the issue is similar and in this case did not help me.

Resolved: Major problem was that i wanted to 'see' the data and compare it. I was terribly wrong! Converted all to byte[] and it worked like a charm !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to reproduce PHP's pack("H\*") function in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508193/trying-to-reproduce-phps-packh-function-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I tried exactly that approach and in this case it is not the answer. Not sure if H40 is somehow different.

Comment: I just tried two things. First i did base64string conversions on both sides and they matched! Second i did all bytes to string conversion and they match as well. My guess is the Encoding when i convert them back to string. I will investigate this further.